# Prove that$ f(\varphi ( \overline{x}))=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, roots

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and let
$\langle f(x)\rangle$ denote the ideal it generates.  Let $R$
be a ring. Define a ring homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\rightarrow R$.

Prove that $f(\varphi(\overline{x}))=0$, where $\overline{x}$ is  just  an  abbreviation  for  the  coset $x+\langle f(x)\rangle$.

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have an answer. Do you want that, or a hint?

Comment: @feralin Thanks so much. It would be good if you could just provide the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n$. Now let $\pi : \mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z[x] / \langle f\rangle$ be the projection (ring) homomorphism $\pi(p) = p + \langle f\rangle$, so that we want to prove
$$f(\varphi(\pi(x))) = 0.$$
This is quite simple, by using the ring homomorphism properties
$$\varphi(\pi(p + q)) = \varphi(\pi(p)) + \varphi(\pi(q))$$
$$\varphi(\pi(pq)) = \varphi(\pi(p))\varphi(\pi(q))$$
$$\varphi(\pi(1_{\mathbb Z[x]})) = 1_R$$
for any $p, q \in \mathbb Z[x]$. Note that this last property, along with the additivity property, gives us (by induction) that $$\varphi(\pi(n)) = \varphi(\pi(n \cdot 1_{\mathbb Z[x]})) = n \cdot \varphi(\pi(1_{\mathbb Z[x]})) = n \cdot 1_R = n,$$ where in any ring $R$ we implicitly write $1 = 1_R$, $2 = 1_R + 1_R$, $3 = 1_R + 1_R + 1_R$, $-1 = -1_R$, etc.

Now we have
$$\begin{align*}
f(\varphi(\pi(x)) &= a_0 + a_1 \varphi(\pi(x)) + a_2 \varphi(\pi(x))^2 + \cdots + a_n \varphi(\pi(x))^n \\
&= \varphi(\pi(a_0)) + \varphi(\pi(a_1))\varphi(\pi(x)) + \varphi(\pi(a_2))\varphi(\pi(x^2)) + \cdots + \varphi(\pi(a_n))\varphi(\pi(x^n)) \\
&= \varphi(\pi(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n)) \\
&= \varphi(\pi(f)) \\
&= \varphi(0_{\mathbb Z[x]/\langle f\rangle}) \\
&= 0_R.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Why is it the case that $a_i =  φ(π(a_i))$

Comment: I'll edit the answer to explain.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have acccpted your answer. I would really appreciate if you could have a look at this question(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160471/prove-the-bijection-between-the-set-of-homomorphisms-and-the-set-of-roots), which is highly related.

Comment: The other question seems interesting, but I'll have to take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Although there is an answer now, I am not quite sure if I understand correctly. Thanks so much!