# Prove the bijection between the set of homomorphisms and the set of roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, roots

[image]

In the above question, I have mangaged to prove that $r_\varphi$ is a root of $f(x)$, namely, $f(\varphi(\overline{x}))=0$. So that can be used as a known fact. I am now trying to prove that the function mapping $\varphi$ to $r_\varphi$ is a bijection from the set of homomorphisms $\varphi$ to the set of roots of $f(x)$ in $R$.  I have managed to prove that this function is injective but do not know how to prove that it is surjective. Can someone help me, please? Thanks so much.

Comment: What is the source of the question? A book? It is quite interesting, and I want to read more related to this.

Comment: @feralin It is not from a book, and it seems that this question is completely newly designed rather than picked from a book. But in page 9 of this notes, there is a quite related field version of it:http://www.math.columbia.edu/~rf/galoisnotes.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a root $r \in R$ of $f$, let $\varphi$ be the homomorphism given by evaluation at $r$, that is,
\begin{align*}
\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[x] &\to R\\
g &\mapsto g(r) \, .
\end{align*}
Then $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism and $\langle f \rangle \subseteq \ker(\varphi)$, so $\varphi$ descends to a well-defined homomorphism $\overline{\varphi}: \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle f \rangle \to R$ on the quotient.  Moreover,
$$
\overline{\varphi}(\overline{x}) = \varphi(x) = r
$$
so $r = r_\overline{\varphi}$, as desired.

Comment: It make some sense to me. But we have never been told that $\phi$ is exacely a evaluation map, how can we assume that? Moreover, how can we conclude the bijection relationship then?

Comment: On this track, I find that given a fixed root $r$ of $f(x)$ in $R$, we can always define the map $\varphi$ to be a evaluation map on $r$ and thus a homomorphism. And by using the mapping property of quotient rings we know that there exist a map $\overline{\varphi}$ that sends the root $\overline{x}$ in the quotient ring to the root $r$ in $R$. Thus we can conclude that for all roots in $R$, there exists a map which send a root $\overline{x}$ in the quotient ring to the root $r$ in $R$. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't understand your first comment.  To show surjectivity, you need to show that for each root $r \in R$ of $f$, there is some homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to R$ such that $r = r_\varphi = \varphi(\overline{x})$.  I have produced such a map: the map induced by evaluation at $r$.

Comment: Yes, your second comment is a restatement of the argument in my answer.